# Is it allowed to load your own ads in iPhone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval, itunes-store

Is it allowed to load your own ads in iPhone app? I mean, I want to periodically load some ad images from internet to the app, while my user uses it without using iAds network. Is it allowed by Apple? I have read AppStore Review Guidelines and found no restrictions, if the App is not designed only for ads.

Comment: Let me rephrase what he's really asking: So, if I have aan app that loads banner add service, and one or more of these ads is malicious and redirects the visitor to a site with an exploit kit, then it will sneak by the app checking process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is allowed and not a subject endangering the Apple approval process.

Answer (score 2):

sure it is.
that's what i do here with my free "lite" app:

http://itunes.apple.com/app/i-love-valmalenco-lite/id459172948?mt=8%20target=

i use an iAd, but when no ads are available (most of the time)
 i use my own banner which links to the iStore address of my "fullVersion" app
(so... a very personal ad of my own... but i know of examples apps which use other commercial ads as adsense...)

Comment: Plus, is it ok to display screenshots on Appstore without the ads?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can load other networks ads too if you want. Or just roll your own.

[MobClix](http://developer.mobclix.com) is good in that it provides a framework that includes iAds.